# How to get the Ingestion time of an event when the time characteristic is event-time?

Tags: apache-flink

I want to evaluate the time costed between an event reaches the system and get finished, and I think getting ingestion time will help, but how to do get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [latency tracking](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#latency-tracking). Alternatively, you can add the processing time directly after the source in a chained [process function](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html) (with `Context->TimerService#currentProcessingTime()`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reply from David, to get the ingest time we can chain the process method with source.
Below code shows the way to get the ingest time. Also in case the same need to be used for metrics to get the difference between ingest time & event time, I have used histogram metric group to do that.

Below code snippet might help you to better understand.

```
DataStream<EventDataMapping> text = env
                .fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5)),"Kafka Source")
                .process(new ProcessFunction<EventDataMapping, EventDataMapping>() {
                    private transient DescriptiveStatisticsHistogram eventVsIngestionTimeLag;
                    private static final int EVENT_TIME_LAG_WINDOW_SIZE = 10_000;

                    @Override
                    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
                        super.open(parameters);

                        eventVsIngestionTimeLag = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().histogram("eventVsIngestionTimeLag",
                                new DescriptiveStatisticsHistogram(EVENT_TIME_LAG_WINDOW_SIZE));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void processElement(EventDataMapping eventDataMapping, Context context, Collector<EventDataMapping> collector) throws Exception {
                        LOG.info("process element event time "+context.timestamp()+" current ingestTime "+context.timerService().currentProcessingTime());
                        eventVsIngestionTimeLag.update(context.timerService().currentProcessingTime() - context.timestamp());
                    }
                }).returns(EventDataMapping.class);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).